# Transfering files from tree to one folder python

Tags: python

I have a program that i just can't get so far. It is a bit of a challenge and maybe someone with more experience could answer this question for me. I need to transfer a number of files from multiple folders that all contain a certain string inputted by the user. 
So far i have been able to figure out how to transfer them within the same folder but not over multiple folders this is what i have:

```
import os
import shutil

FindFile = input("What is the Rain Gauge code you want to transfer? ")

frmDir = "C:\\Users\\BWhitehouse\\Documents\\GVRD\\MonthlySummary_02\\Air Quality"

toDir =  "O:\\0600-0699\\646-031\\400-Work\\BW_Wk\\Rain_Gauges"

for fName in os.listdir(frmDir):
    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(frmDir, fName)):
        for prefix in [FindFile]:
            if fName.startswith(prefix):
                shutil.move(os.path.join(frmDir, fName), toDir)
```

What needs to change so i can iterate over files from different folders and transfer all the files and transferring the files with the user input in part of their name?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
frmDirs = ["C:\\Users\\BWhitehouse\\Documents\\GVRD\\MonthlySummary_02\\Air Quality",
           "C:\\Users\\BWhitehouse\\Documents\\GVRD\\MonthlySummary_03\\Air Quality",
           "C:\\Users\\BWhitehouse\\Documents\\GVRD\\MonthlySummary_04\\Air Quality"
          ]
...

for frmDir in frmDirs:
    for fName in os.listdir(frmDir):
        if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(frmDir, fName)):
            for prefix in [FindFile]:
                if fName.startswith(prefix):
                    shutil.move(os.path.join(frmDir, fName), toDir)
```

maybe?

Comment: that does work! thanks! I am also trying to send those transfered files into folders containing part of the user input. That is the next step trying but not having much success. thanks again!